# Cannot read property 'externalModuleIndicator' of undefined while running unit test using karma and webpack 4

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, karma-webpack

After upgrading my angular project with webpack 4 I am getting below error while running unit test using karma

> [at-loader] Using typescript@2.7.2 from typescript and "tsconfig.json"
>   from demo-app-app\src\tsconfig.json.
>
> [at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...
>
> [at-loader] Checking finished with 1509 errors
>   [at-loader]: Child process failed to process the request:  TypeError: Cannot 
>   read property 'externalModuleIndicator' of undefined
>    at Object.isExternalModule
>   (demo-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:13733:20)  at
>   Object.getAllDependencies
>   (demo-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:75788:46)  at
>   Object.getAllDependencies
>   (demo-app\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:76133:80)  at
>   processEmit
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\checker\runtime.ts:451:24)
>   at
>   demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\checker\runtime.ts:602:6
>   at Object.send
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\checker\runtime.ts:48:6)
>   at Checker.req
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\checker\checker.ts:100:15)
>   at Checker.emitFile
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\checker\checker.ts:105:15)
>   at transform
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:132:26) 
>   at transformationFunction
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:74:40) 
>   at compiler
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:85:21) 
>   at Object.loader
>   (demo-app\node_modules\awesome-typescript-loader\src\index.ts:16:12) 
>   at LOADER_EXECUTION
>   (demo-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:119:14)  at
>   runSyncOrAsync
>   (demo-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:120:4)  at
>   iterateNormalLoaders
>   (demo-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:229:2)  at
>   iterateNormalLoaders
>   (demo-app\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:218:10)
>       <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> 136168 ms: Mark-sweep 1255.3 (1435.8) -> 1242.3 (1435.8) MB, 893.2 /
>   0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].   137084 ms: Mark-sweep 1242.3 (1435.8) -> 1242.3 (1435.8) MB, 915.6 / 0.0 ms
>   [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].   138055 ms:
>   Mark-sweep 1242.3 (1435.8) -> 1248.2 (1408.8) MB, 970.0 / 0.0 ms [last
>   resort gc].   139026 ms: Mark-sweep 1248.2 (1408.8) -> 1254.0 (1408.8)
>   MB, 971.0 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap
>   out of memory

Package Json:

> awesome-typescript-loader:5.0.0-0
>   karma-webpack:2.0.4
>   webpack:4.1.1

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    mode: 'development',

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: ['awesome-typescript-loader', 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'

            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'null'
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
                loader: 'raw'
            },
            {
               enforce: 'post',
               test: /\.(js|ts)$/,
               loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
               include: helpers.root('src'),
               exclude: [
                 /\.(e2e|spec)\.ts$/,
                 /node_modules/
               ]
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
          /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)@angular/,
          helpers.root('./src'),
          {}
        )
    ]
};
```

Please note that I am able to run my angular project without any issue only UT configuration are giving errors.

Answer (score 6):

Update with 'npm update' command. it is solved my issue of the above error.

Comment: please run the command  "npm update" in the terminal of your angular project.

Answer (score 2):

Update to `typescript@2.8.1` could resolve 'externalModuleIndicator' issue (but may break something else)

Comment: typescript@2.8.3 and awesome-typescript-loader@5.0.0, still have the same issue.

Comment: Any resolution for this. I am also facing same problem

Comment: I'm on 3.6.3 and just stumbled upon this issue, it came seemingly out nowhere

Comment: Somehow only happens when using Yarn PnP. Which is a bummer, I would really like to use that.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve a similar issue by replacing `awesome-typescript-loader` with `ts-loader`

Had a similar discussion here

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/karma-webpack/issues/331

Answer (score 0):

For the Yarn users: run `yarn install` in the terminal.